# What is the CUPS administration URL?

Tags: printing

I thought a Google search would instantly provide me the answer. I am **very surprised** it didn't!

I had it stored in my browser... I just typed "CUPS" and it brought the page to me... but I've cleared the history... now I want to get there again.

Answer (score 17):

Changing the search keywords finally brought me the answer:

```
http://localhost:631/
```